# Bind click event for all buttons in app

Tags: extjs

How can I bind event for all buttons in my ExtJS app?
like JQuery:

```js
$('button').click(function(el) {
    console.log($(el).getattr('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

If you're writing a full app following Ext's MVC pattern, you have to instantiate an `Ext.Application` and use a controller with code like the following

- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller
- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#/guide/application_architecture

Sample Code

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Buttons', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'button': {
                click: function() { ... }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The hacked up way is to do a query and bind a separate handler for each button

```
Ext.Array.each(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button'), function(btn)) {
  btn.on('click', function() {...});
};
```